# does anyone have a libxpm example?

Tags: xlib, xcb

This is the dumbest thing but I have tried and tried and I cannot use libxpm.

I have found some snippets of code but very little and what i have found has been very old code that I cannot compile.

My understanding so far is that I need to:

connect to x windows server             (done)
create a window                         (done)
use libxpm to create a pixmap from data (not done)
copy the pixmap to the window           (not done)

If you happen to have a small example lying around or know where to send me that would be great. If you happen to know how to use xcb and libxpm that would be even better. xcb seems to use an integer for it's connection while xlib uses a display struct, I haven't found any examples at all that deal with xcb and libxpm and the connection issue is a deadend for me.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

This may help. If I use ImageMagick's `convert`, I can convert a `JPEG` to an `XPM` and that may help you see how they are supposed to look.

```
convert image.jpg image.xpm
```

And we can look at it like this:

```
more image.xpm
/* XPM */
static char *background[] = {
/* columns rows colors chars-per-pixel */
"906 603 181 2 ",
"   c #040403",
".  c #080704",
"X  c #070803",
"o  c #090906",
"O  c #060608",
...
...
```

Comment: Hi Mark!Thanks for posting. I have my xpm files. I have read the libxpm manual and I understand the file formaat

Comment: The XPM Format:
[https://www.xfree86.org/current/xpm.pdf#page=8](https://www.xfree86.org/current/xpm.pdf#page=8)

Comment: X PixMap (XPM): [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap)

Answer (score 1):

The libXpm sources include a simple “show xpm” command, but it still uses Xlib & Xt, not xcb:

https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXpm/tree/sxpm/sxpm.c